# xdotool not working with sxhkd?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, troubleshooting, xdotool, sxhkd

```
ctrl + 2
  xdotool type Test Message
```

Added the above line to `sxhkdrc` with no effect. Using different commands works, but for some reason any `xdotool` command doesn't work... If i run that command in dmenu or terminal it works. `man sxhkd` says the commands are executed as `SHELL -c COMMAND` where in my case `SHELL = zsh` and command is the one above. Running that on console also works, but when i press `ctrl+2` it doesn't. I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely `xdotool` is typing the message while you're still holding `ctrl`, which leads to `ctrl+shift+t`, `ctrl+e`, ... to be pressed instead, therefore not writing anything.

Comment: What is a solution or work around to this?